# Removing part of filename with bash

Tags: bash, loops, glob, file-rename, batch-rename

Why this script does not work?

```
for filename in bre*; do 
    rename 's/bre//'; 
done
```

I have files starting with bre in the directory and I would like to delete this part from filenames. It is running and nothing will happen and it is not finished. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't tell `rename` what files it should rename.

You don't need the loop, since you can use a wildcard for the filename arguments to `rename`

```
rename 's/bre//' bre*
```